# How do I rectify the error getting in my code to find Euler's Totient. Can anybody rectify the part where I'm getting error?

Tags: c

This the example of Euler's Totient. Euler’s Totient function ?(n) for an input n is count of numbers in {1, 2, 3, …, n} that are relatively prime to n, i.e., the numbers whose GCD (Greatest Common Divisor) with n is 1.
I'm getting struck in the `main()` function. As per my intuition, it should calculate the sum of every pair of gcd which is equal to 1 for every number.

The output is iterating infinite times when it is entering into the `hcf` function.  If I remove the `hcf` function just to check whether the pairs which the function is taking are correct, it is printing them in the proper order. But, if I add the `hcf()` in the main function, it is going into an infinite loop rather printing the sum of gcds of pairs which are equal to 1.

```
     #include<stdio.h>
      int temp,a,b,n,sum=0,i,j, gcd;

        int hcf(a,b)
        {    for(i=1; i <= a && i <= b; i++)
             {
                 if(a%i==0 && b%i==0)
                     gcd = i;
             }
                 return gcd;
        }


        void main()
        {
           printf("Enter the value of n");
           scanf("%d",&n);
           for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
           {
               for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
               {
                   printf("%d,%d\n",j,i);
                   if(hcf(j,i)==temp)
                       {
                           sum=sum+1;
                       }

                }
                printf("%d\n",sum);
                sum=0;

           }

        }
```

Comment: did you try using a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

**Root cause analysis:**

The problem is you are incrementing `i` (with **global** scope) in 2 places: 1. for loop in `main`. 2. for loop in `hcf`. The result is `j` in the for loop inside `main` never reaches `i` and you get an infinite loop.

---

**Solution Description:**

A possible correction is to limit the scope of `i` inside `hcf`:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int temp,a,b,n,sum=0,i,j, gcd;


int hcf(int a, int b)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= a && i <= b; i++)
    {
        if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0)
            gcd = i;
    }
    return gcd;
}


int main()
{
    printf("Enter the value of n");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            printf("%d,%d\n", j, i);
            if (hcf(j, i) == temp)
            {
                sum = sum + 1;
            }

        }
        printf("%d\n", sum);
        sum = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you..It helped me a lot. But, can you explain briefly about the scope which you are telling about?

Comment: I only added `int i;` at the beginning of `hcf()` function. by adding this line, I have disconnected `i` in this function from `i` in `main`. After the change, each of them is a different variable / memory.